# `User` is not part of the schema for this Realm - How to find out whether 'User' exists?

Tags: android, realm

Say I wanna know whether User is empty.

This is my code:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    User results1 = myRealm.where(User.class).findFirst();
    return results1 == null;
}
```

If it's the first time using the app, I need to know that, because if that's the case, I need to ask the user to fill the form. (It's not really authentication, just a simple form).

In this situation, how can I know whether User exists without having to create a record.

Edit:

Here's the stack:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ga.xuser/com.example.ga.xuser.View.Activities.Profile}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User is not part of the schema for this Realm
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause - absent schema migration. You need to add new objects to existing database schema when you create new `RealmModel` class (`User` in your case). Or you can remove database and in that case Realm will create new schema which will contain all of you models.

#### Migration

You can found very clean sample in [Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) paragraph of ducementation. If more details required, see also [migration sample app](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample) on GitHub.

P.S. If keyword `this` in expession `Realm.getInstance(this)` - it's an instance of `Context`, you use super old Realm version. `Realm.getInstance(Context)` was removed in 0.83.0 if I remember correctly. I siggest to update to latest version of Realm ([cerrent 3.2.1](https://realm.io/docs/java/3.2.1/)).

Comment: How can I know whether there's no schema before migration? Because I must know whether it's the first time using the app

Comment: Upgrading to 3.2.1 make it work out of the box. I simply check if results are null now. It doesn't crash.